# Tikzpicture as background

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a `tikzpicture` and put it as background on one slide. So far I have this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

% background
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,scale=2.5]
 \pgftransformcm{1}{0.1}{0.2}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
 % draw the grid
 \draw[step=.3cm,black!10,line width=0.01cm] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \foreach \x in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
     \foreach \y in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
         \filldraw[black!10] (\x,\y) circle (0.4pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> First
\item<+-> Second
\item<+-> Third
\item<+-> Fourth
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but the background grid is covering also the title. How can I make so that the picture starts from just below the title bar of the frame?

Answer (score 5):

If manual checking of needed values is OK, it remains to change transformation and translation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

% background
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,scale=2.5]
% \pgftransformcm{1}{0.1}{0.2}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgftransformcm{-1}{-0.1}{-0.2}{-1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-3cm}}
 % draw the grid
 \draw[step=.3cm,black!10,line width=0.01cm] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \foreach \x in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
     \foreach \y in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
         \filldraw[black!10] (\x,\y) circle (0.4pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> First
\item<+-> Second
\item<+-> Third
\item<+-> Fourth
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this?  Just add `\earmark` to any frame you want with this background.  Based on my answer at [How to visually "earmark" certain slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307702/how-to-visually-earmark-certain-slides/307708#307708)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground{%
  \smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}}
\def\earmark{%
  \atxy{.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.5,overlay,scale=2.5]
 \pgftransformcm{1}{0.1}{0.2}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
 % draw the grid
 \draw[step=.3cm,black!10,line width=0.01cm] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \foreach \x in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
     \foreach \y in {-3.9,-3.6,...,3.9}
         \filldraw[black!10] (\x,\y) circle (0.4pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\earmark
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> First
\item<+-> Second
\item<+-> Third
\item<+-> Fourth
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]