# Beamer: How to place a logo in the left and the bottom?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning, page-numbering

I want to place my logo in the left and at the bottom of the slide.
I'm using the Darmstadt theme. The number of the slide is put in the right.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Darmstadt}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \date{\today} 
 \subject{Thesis}  
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo.png}} 
  \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 {Hello World}
  You are Welcome

  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a MWE? With `\usetheme{Darmstadt}` alone, there is no slide number. Do you want you logo above or within the footline?

Comment: I added a MWE. I want it to be placed at the same level of the page number. Thank you

Comment: While different, it may be applicable: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307702/how-to-visually-earmark-certain-slides

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the image to the definition of the footline:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Darmstadt}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \date{\today} 
 \subject{Thesis}  
 \usepackage{graphbox}

 \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \includegraphics[align=c, height=0.5cm]{example-image}%
        \hfill%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
        \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em%
 }

  \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 {Hello World}
  You are Welcome

  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic:

You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, as it is already provided by beamer.