# Align Text in Footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I am new to LaTeX - Beamer. I am trying to create a template, and am almost done. However, there I am unable to align the text in the footline.

If i play around with the `hspace` `vspace` it increases the width of the footline which is something i do not desire. I was wondering if there was a way to vertically align the text in the footline to be in the center of the bar.

```
\newlength\barwidth
\setlength\barwidth{24pt} % width of bars set here
\setbeamercolor*{footline}{fg=orange,bg=black} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,left]{footline}% 
\includegraphics[width=\barwidth,height=\barwidth]{img/GGLogo.png}      
~\hfill \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont% 
usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}\hspace{0em}\vspace{0em}\textbf\inserttitle%
\end{beamercolorbox} }
```

Comment: You could use something like `\parbox[c][<height>]{<width>}{\mbox{}\vfill<contents>\vfill}`

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks, while this does work. It does not align the text vertically to the image.

Comment: Do the same with the image.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks. And adding '\centering' brought it to center align in the box. If you post it as an answer. **I think i can accept it due to my reputation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer (and shamelessly stealing the MWE from @samcarter; thanks for that)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength\barwidth
\setlength\barwidth{24pt} % width of bars set here
\setbeamercolor*{footline}{fg=orange,bg=black} 
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{series=\bfseries, size=\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=2pt]{footline}%
      \parbox[c]{0pt}{\makebox[0pt][l]{% doesn't use any horizontal space
        \includegraphics[height=\barwidth,width=\barwidth]{example-image}%
      }}%
      \hspace{0.1\textwidth}%
      \parbox[c]{0.8\textwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\inserttitle%
      }%
      \hspace{0.1\textwidth}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\title{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\title{This is longer title, which might take up too much space}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Beamer: How to place a logo in the left and the bottom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341697/beamer-how-to-place-a-logo-in-the-left-and-the-bottom)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength\barwidth
\setlength\barwidth{24pt} % width of bars set here
\setbeamercolor*{footline}{fg=orange,bg=black} 
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{series=\bfseries, size=\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=2pt]{footline}%
    \includegraphics[align=c, height=\barwidth]{example-image}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
    \inserttitle\hfill\kern1em%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{graphbox}

\title{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcater Thank you for that. However, as stated in my question, i am looking to align the text in the center of the black bar. and be center aligned with the image.

Comment: @AlyAbdelaziz I am not sure I understand you comment. Are you looking for horizontal alignment? Then add a `\hfill` after `\inserttitle`

Comment: @samcarter I think he was asking for both, vertical and horizontal alignment.

Comment: @Skillmon I don't see any indication of this in the question, but probably your assumption is reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: @samcarter me neither, but his comments and the question combined indicate it.

Comment: @samcarter Both Alignments. Guess i was not that clear in the question because i kind of figured the horizontal alignment bit. I really appreciate the help and input from the both of you.